# How to concatenate element-wise a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings and I want to concatenate the elements of the list in the following way:

`before = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

`after = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd']`

I am not sure of how the above operation is called.

However, I tried using the range method:

`after = [before[i]+before[i+1] for i in range(0,len(before),2)]`

but it results in: `after = ['ab', 'cd']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method doesn't allow overlap since your index is increasing by 2.

A quickfix would be

```
after = [before[i]+before[i+1] for i in range(len(before)-1)]
```

But I would rather `zip` the list with a sliced version of itself:

```
before = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

after = [a+b for a,b in zip(before,before[1:])]

>>> after
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
from itertools import tee

before = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
c, n = tee(before, 2)
next(n)

after = [cu + ne for cu, ne in zip(c, n)]
print(after)
```

**Output**

```
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

**Further**

1. [Itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 0):

In the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) there is a useful recipe you can use:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

>>> map(lambda x: ''.join(x), pairwise(before))
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```